# Transaction was deadlocked 

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, transactions

I get the following sql exception :
Transaction  was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction. Uncommittable transaction is detected at the end of the batch. The transaction is rolled back.
I don't have any transactions in any stored procedures, I do the transcation from .net and I always call them with using . 
Have you guys met this before?

Answer (score 3):

A transaction is a transaction, no matter where started. Whether in c# or the RDBMS.

Your `using` issues BEGIN TRANSCATION effectively.

[MSDN (for SQL Server 2000 but still valid)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213042%28SQL.80%29.aspx) recommends you retry automatically when a deadlock is detected, Rather than write code here, there are many results on Google for you to peruse.

Comment: IMO MSDN is just plain wrong on this. If you just automatically retry without any thinking, you are quite likely to overwrite someone else's changes a.k.a. lost changes.

Comment: @AlexKuznetsov: I've found deadlocks don't usually occur on the same row for the same action, but on the same table/page/index by another process. If you have minimal write paths on to a row, 2 concurrent processes using the same code/action shouldn't deadlock. However, an INSERT parent to child, with a DELETE child to parent could well do. In my case, I'd look for other changes anyway: I don't know how long the data has been on screen for edit for example.

Comment: I am not with you on "concurrent processes using the same code/action shouldn't deadlock" - here is a repro that shows how a stored proc dealocks with the same proc form another connection: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2008/11/27/defensive-database-programming-if-statement-vs-where-clause.aspx

Comment: and come to think of it, if we are a deadlock victim, somebody might have modified the same data we are trying to update. Does it really matter if it was modified by the same code?

Answer (score 0):

When using the transaction you need to be careful as by default it sets the isolation level to serialisable. When the connection is released back into the pool it will still have that level set. This can seriously harm concurrency.